# Intercepting .onion Sites with BurpSuite + Tor

Tags: proxy, onion-routing

I'm stuck on this. I've configure the Tor browser to the BurpSuite proxy so I can intercept.It work for regular web addresses but not .onion sites. Does anybody know why? And what can I do to fix it? Thx in advance for the help!!

Comment: Try to use regular Firefox - the Tor Browser's attunement is to communicate with a local tor instance in uninterrupted/unintercepted manner, so you better use a regular browser. Try Firefox add-on FoxyProxy - and use this with your security suite